# ¿Por que no funciona la funcion move_uploaded_file() de PHP?

Tags: php

Tengo un problema, llevo bastante rato tratando de hacer un formulario en donde un usuario suba una imagen al servidor, creo que el problema esta en la dirección de destino, pero he tratado de cambiar esa direccion muchas veces y sigue sin funcionar,

**HTML**

```html
<form class="row" action="php/cambiarFoto.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="imagen">
    <button type="submit" name="enviar">Guardar</button>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```php
foreach ($_FILES['imagen'] as $x => $y) {
echo "$x: $y <br>";
}
echo "<hr>";
$nombre = $_FILES['imagen']['name'];
$tipo = $_FILES['imagen']['type'];
$tamagno = $_FILES['imagen']['size'];
$error = $_FILES['imagen']['error'];
$rutaTemporal = $_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'];


if ($tipo == "image/jpg" or $tipo == "image/png" or $tipo == "image/gif" or $tipo == "image/jpeg"){
    if ($tamagno <= 500000) {
        if ($error == 0){
            move_uploaded_file($rutaTemporal,"../../img/perfil/" . $nombre);
        } else {
            header("Location: ../?error");
            die();
        }

    } else {
        header("Location:../?err_tamagno_imagen");
        die();
    }

}else{
    header("Location:../?err_tipo_imagen");
    die();
}
```

En si no me marca ningún error, simplemente no sube el archivo y me devuelve FALSE la función

Comment: Bienveniso a [es.so]. Trata de explicar un poco mas el problema, indicanos que error te da o que es lo que esta sucediendo, asi como indicar que estructura de directorios tienes.

Comment: En su lugar utiliza la función `copy()` de PHP. Cuéntanos como te va.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya resolví el problema, a la hora de poner la ruta tuve que poner la variable dentro de las comillas es decir:

```
move_uploaded_file($rutaTemporal,"../../img/perfil/" . $nombre);
```

Lo cambie por:

```
move_uploaded_file($rutaTemporal,"../../img/perfil/$nombre");
```

Después de eso funcionó perfectamente el sistema